# Collect all the div id inside the table - webdriver using c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium

```
<table id="tblRenewalAgent" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="form-row">
<div id="trStatus" style="">
<div id="trFees" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trFees1" class="form-row ctrl-column" style="">
<div id="trFilingReceipt" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trComments" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trContact" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trEmail" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trPhone" class="form-row" style="">
<div id="trCell" class="form-row" style="">
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-row ctrl-column">
<div id="trAmountPaid">
<div id="trBalanceDue" class="form-row">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Expected:

i want to collect all the div id and store it an array
im using c#. how can i do it? please help me guys

Comment: Your question is currently unclear. Is this HTML in a string inside of a C# program? If this is the case, two options I would consider would be: 1) A regex to look for each ID inside a DIV or 2) HtmlAgilityPack (to clean up malformed HTML) and then use XPATH to select all DIV statements into a collection which will then allow you to SELECT all IDs from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
            List<WebElement> totalrow  =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                    .presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("tblRenewalAgent"));

        for (int i = 0; i <= totalrow.size(); i++) {

            String clasRow = //form-row;

            try {

                WebElement element = ExpectedBehaviors
                        .expectPresenceofElementBy(driver, By.class(clasRow),
                                getAlertTimeout());

                if (element.getText().trim().equals("EXPECTED VALUE")) {

                    //"PERFORM YOUR ACTION"                     
                    break;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //"You can add your exception and error message

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to create an XmlDocument. You will need to include the System.Xml namespace like so:

```
using System.Xml;
```

Below I have created a sample application which I will explain:

First you should create the xml document object and load in some xml. For demonstration I have included your HTML literally, but you could replace this by loading in a file for example.

```
var html = new XmlDocument();
        html.LoadXml(@"<table id='tblRenewalAgent' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class='form-row'/>
                            <div id='trStatus' style=''/>
                            <div id='trFees' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div id='trFees1' class='form-row ctrl-column' style=''/>
                            <div id='trFilingReceipt' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div id='trComments' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div id='trContact' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div id='trEmail' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div id='trPhone' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div id='trCell' class='form-row' style=''/>
                            <div class='form-row'/>
                            <div class='form-row ctrl-column'/>
                            <div id='trAmountPaid'/>
                            <div id='trBalanceDue' class='form-row'/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>");
```

You were also missing closing tags for your divs, I have made them self closing for this demonstration.

I also created a static generic List of strings to which we will add all of our id strings like so:

```
static List<string> ids = new List<string>();
```

I placed this above my Main method.

Lastly, you should call the *WalkForIds* method I have defined below on each of the document child nodes:

```
foreach (XmlNode elem in html.ChildNodes)
    WalkForIds(elem);
```

The WalkForIds method recursively looks through the HTML in order to find all ids. Here is the definition:

```
    private static void WalkForIds(XmlNode node)
    {
        if(node.HasChildNodes)
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
                WalkForIds(child);
        if (node.Attributes == null) return;
        foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
            if (attr.Name == "id")
                ids.Add(attr.Value);

    }
```

After this, you should find that the *ids* generic List will contain all ids in the HTML.